# Write to new innerHTML

Tags: javascript

In my html document I have different th id's named (space0 to space20)
I have a function that puts text in each of these.
Right now I use this code:

```
var space0= document.getElementById('space0');
    space0.innerHTML = space0.innerHTML + random[0];
var space1= document.getElementById('space1');
    space1.innerHTML = space1.innerHTML + random[1];
```

This works fine, but as the list goes on it becomes very tedious.
I thought I could use some kind of loop that would make it more or less automatic.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
var space[i]= document.getElementById('space[i]');
        space[i].innerHTML = space[i].innerHTML + random[i];
```

But it just generates a blank space. Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you attempted to do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var space = document.getElementById('space' + i);
  space.innerHTML += random[i];
}
```

Be aware resetting the `innerHTML` will get rid of the internal state of the elements (event listeners, custom properties, checkedness, ...). That's why I recommend [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var space = document.getElementById('space' + i);
  space.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', random[i]);
}
```

Read [insertAdjacentHTML() Enables Faster HTML Snippet Injection](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/11/insertadjacenthtml-enables-faster-html-snippet-injection/) for more information.

Also consider using the class `"space"` instead of `"space" + i` IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the following line:

```
var space[i]= document.getElementById('space[i]');
```

You want to get the id dynamically, so you need to do the following:

```
 space[i]= document.getElementById('space' + i');
```

This generates you for each loop the id 'space' + the current value of your counter i.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
document.getElementById('space[i]')
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('space' + i)
```

Although I didn't test it, this should resolve your problem. In the first case the function is looking for an element that has the id 'space[i]', in the second case you construct the id by appending the number to the string 'space' so you'll get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for the get element is not correct. Please review the code attached. It runs as well.

```js
/*  COPY && PASTE   */
function epicRandomString(b){for(var a=(Math.random()*eval("1e"+~~(50*Math.random()+50))).toString(36).split(""),c=3;c<a.length;c++)c==~~(Math.random()*c)+1&&a[c].match(/[a-z]/)&&(a[c]=a[c].toUpperCase());a=a.join("");a=a.substr(~~(Math.random()*~~(a.length/3)),~~(Math.random()*(a.length-~~(a.length/3*2)+1))+~~(a.length/3*2));if(24>b)return b?a.substr(a,b):a;a=a.substr(a,b);if(a.length==b)return a;for(;a.length<b;)a+=epicRandomString();return a.substr(0,b)};
/*  COPY && PASTE   */


for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var space = document.getElementById('space'+i);
        space.innerHTML = space.innerHTML + epicRandomString(4);
}
```

```html
<div id="space0"></div>
<div id="space1"></div>
<div id="space2"></div>
<div id="space3"></div>
<div id="space4"></div>
<div id="space5"></div>
<div id="space6"></div>
```